# Android - using Adapter with object

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have an object called "EntityType en" which contains a string "Name" i want to use Array Adapter to check the index of the given object but without defining my list in the R.layout because it is defined in by the object.

What I am trying to do is showing my data (array) in a menu dialog that lets the user select the desired "Name".

Comment: Please show your approach first and explain better what your issue with the standard way of using an arrayadapter is.

Comment: ok done I edited it

Comment: You didn't edit but posted as a new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38683291/show-list-in-alertdialog

Comment: I found a solution...thanks ;)