# Show list in AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am using an alert dialog that shows a menu on the beginning of the app, I want the dialog to show me 2 values which are "name"s from an object, here is the code of the alert dialog:

```
public void showDialog() {

    EntityType en = new EntityType();
    ArrayList array = ApplicationController.entities;

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Pick one");
    builder.setItems(array, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // I want to write my code here
        }
    });

    builder.show();
}
```

`EntityType` is my object that contain a string "name" and `ApplicationController.entities` contains the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void showDialog() {

    EntityType en = new EntityType();
    ArrayList array = ApplicationController.entities;

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Pick one");
    ArrayList<String> displayValues=new ArrayList<>();
      for (Entity entity : array) {
         displayValues.add(entity.name);
      }

      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array);
      final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      builder.setTitle("Pick one");
      builder.setSingleChoiceItems(displayValues, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Entity selectedItem = array[which];
         }
      });    


    builder.show();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the below code.. it works for me... :)

```
AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builderSingle.setIcon(R.drawable.green_tick_add);
    builderSingle.setTitle("Choose..");

    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item);
    arrayAdapter.add("Change Photo");
    arrayAdapter.add("Remove Photo");

    builderSingle.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    builderSingle.setAdapter(arrayAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String strName = arrayAdapter.getItem(which);

        }
    });
    builderSingle.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog);
adapt.add("your entity name");
```

then edit diaolog code :

```
builder.setAdapter(adapt, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            //write code here
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an ArrayAdapter holding your EntityType names and adding them to it:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
adapt.add("your entity name");
```

Then on the dialog:

```
builder.setAdapter(adapt, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            //Your code here
        }
    });
```

Hope it helps